# Field initialization in constructor corrupts memory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

For some reasone field initialization in constructor from UNIT test, corrupts memory.

I have the following class

```
//.h 
    class Entity
    {
    public:
...
    Entity();

    private:
        unsigned int _nextOperatorId;
        unsigned int _operators[30][4]; //from consts
... 
    }

//.cpp
Entity::Entity() : _operators(), _nextOperatorId(1)
    {
      /* If i run this from unit test i see:
         _operators [0] 0x0569bb38 {3452816845, 3452816845, 3452816845, 3452816845, 1}
         _operators [1] 0x0569bb4c {3452816845, 0, 0, 0, 0} 
         _operators [2] 0x0569bb4c {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        ... (all other rows are zeroes).

        If i delete _nextOperatorId(1) initialiazation, or if i run constructor from       console app, here all as expected - all rows in operators array are zeroes * /   


    }
```

I run this in VS unit test class initializer like this:

```
private
        Entity* entity;
public:
        TEST_METHOD_INITIALIZE(ClassInitialize)
        {
            entity = new Entity();
        }
```

So why does memory corruypted after i add _nextOperatorId(1)? All looks so simple..

Comment: Post a complete example that compiles.

Comment: I'm curious to know if the same problem happens with the initializer list order reversed (i.e. it matches your decls in your class). Note: it shouldn't matter; they should always be initialized per the standard in top-down decl order, not initializer list order, but I wouldn't put it past MS to have dropped this ball.

Answer (score 2):

There is a known bug in VC++ compiler; unless it is fixed in your version you unfortunately can't rely on VC++ for value-initializing your class members as required by C++ standards.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/564268/c-value-initialization

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/746973/incorrect-c-11-value-initialization-for-type-with-implicitly-declared-but-non-trivial-default-constructor